# Bugged CSS animation in Firefox using Intersection Observer

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, css-animations, intersection-observer

I'm using Intersection Observer to add a class to specific elements as they enter the viewport. The class triggers a CSS animation.

Specifically, I'm adding `.swipe` to any `.highlight` elements that enter the viewport.

In Firefox only, the animation runs on time but gets cut about 20% short.

```
<div class="description">
<p><span class="highlight">Travel companion app</span> that displays nearby restaurants, hotels...</p>
</div>
```

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add('swipe')
    }
  })
});

document.querySelectorAll('.highlight').forEach((i) => {
  if (i) {
    observer.observe(i);
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.swipe {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
}

.swipe::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  animation: swipe 1.5s ease-out 1s forwards;
}

.swipe--delay::after {
  background-color: black;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.swipe h1 {
  color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade 0.01s ease-out 1.75s forwards;
}

.swipe h2,
.swipe h3 {
  color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade 0.01s ease-out 2.25s forwards;
}

@keyframes swipe {
  0% {
    right: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add HTML to snippet

Comment: When you say it gets cut do you mean that there is about 20% more of the animation to run but it stops, leaving part of the highlight showing on the left hand side?

Comment: @AHaworth text is black, background is white. from the left, a black "highlighter" runs across the text until the end of the `.highlight` span. In firefox, because of `text-align: justify`, the highlighter runs about 80% from left to right. Some of the span wouldn't be highlighted. The more a specific line of text was justified or spread out, the more the animation was clipped.

Answer (score 0):

The `.description` div had a `text-align: justify` property. Firefox seems to calculate the width of justified inline elements differently than other browsers. There may be another way to fix this, but for now I'm happy removing the `text-align: justify` property altogether.